# POS ofbiz I need up my data

Tags: ofbiz

Now i need my data up to POS ofbiz I can't config Who ever config POS ofbiz I need guide with me.

Thank you
I'm sorry I can type Eng a little bit

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't really good enough English. I can't understand you. Ask someone to translate your question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read technical documentation for the Apache OFBiz system, specifically the POS setup, at <strike>https://cwiki.apache.org/OFBTECH/apache-ofbiz-technical-production-setup-guide.html#ApacheOFBizTechnicalProductionSetupGuide-POSSetupProcess</strike>

*Update:*

As JacquesLeRoux writes, the documentation is now available at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/POS+System.

Comment: Hi David, as suggested Jean-François, I'd like to edit your comment with mine, hence the link would be changed. Do you agree?

Comment: @JacquesLeRoux this answer is 5 years old. You can edit. And David can roll back to the non-working link if he wants (I doubt he will)

Answer (score 1):

The link to the OFBiz POS official documentation above has changed, here you go : [OFBiz Pos Doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/POS+System)

Here is an excerpt of the OFBiz POS official documentation

The last released version with the POS available was R12.04.06. It's though still available in the R14.12 and 15.12 non released branches. It'll not be available with the R16 release and further. All the POS official documentation is reliable and usable before revision 1754402

Comment: I really wonder why giving right and up to date documentation deserves an anonymous -1. That does not give desire to continue to help users :/

Comment: the question is pretty bad & unclear. Maybe you should propose an edit of the accepted answer instead to update the link (the accepted answer is also bad since it's a link only answer, and the question asks for a link to some doc which is also off-topic). Probably explains the downvote.

Comment: Thanks Jean-François, I'll consider it

Comment: hey, the downvote has gone away (wasn't mine, but probably influenced by the latest comments ... :))

Comment: Thanks Jean-François, it seems David edited already, it's ok with me like that, I just striked out the old 404 link